# CORS : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: d3.js, gruntjs, lodash, fuseki

I am working on a D3 - grunt-cli application in which I am facing a CORS issue when sending post requests to a Fuseki Server.

```
function saveToFusekiFunc() {
    document.getElementById('fileid').click();
    document.getElementById('fileid').value = null;

    d3.select("#fileid").on("change", function() {
      var contents;
      var file = d3.select("#fileid").property("files")[0];
      console.log(file);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
      contents = e.target.result;
      console.log(contents);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "http://localhost:3030/Test/";

    xhr.open(
      "POST",
       url ,
      true
    );

    //xhr.setRequestHeader('Data-Type', 'jsonp');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/turtle;charset=utf-8');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000/');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
    }
    xhr.send(contents);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);

    })


  }
```

Above is my code with which I try to make the request. This only works if I enable the CORS plugin in my browser extension.

I have also tried to include the access by making changes to the gruntfile.js middlewares. But it did not help. From which I am almost sure that this is some issue at the server end.

My dependenices are as shown below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "d3": "^3.5.6",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.1.0"
  }
```

Have tried most of the solutions found online but nothing has worked other than directly blocking the CORS check in the browser. I am trying to make a request from 'http://localhost:8000/' to the Fuseki Server 'http://localhost:3030/'.

The error I am getting is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3030/Test/' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Request headers:

[image]

Also checked the web.xml file of the Fuseki configuration which seems to have the CORS settings:

```
<!-- CORS -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <!-- Ported and standalone version of org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter -->
    <filter-class>org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- Defaults may be fine --> 
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
      <param-value>Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified, Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>exposedHeaders</param-name>
      <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
```

Comment: The code seems to set headers in the request with headers. The request needs "Origin:", see `allowedHeaders` above: the response with have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly the mistake I was doing.

Comment: Could you explain how you fixed this? I don't understand the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CORS request used the `Origin` header and the response will be the headers such as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

The code sets response headers in the request with headers and does not have an "Origin".

Answer (score 0):

For CORS to work, you have to enable it on the target server, so in this case, in your Fuseki server. From the [Wikipedia doc on CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing):

> Note that in the CORS architecture, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is being set by the external web service (service.example.com), not the original web application server (www.example.com). Here, service.example.com uses CORS to permit the browser to authorize www.example.com to make requests to service.example.com.

Here's a gist, although fair warning, I have not tried it on my server:
https://gist.github.com/danja/e8ecbf7e51f7a2616122

Comment: I have updated my question including the settings as seen from the Fuseki file. It seems to have the CORS settings. Still doesn't work.